# grpc: how to return a reference to another service

Tags: protocol-buffers, grpc

I am writing a service which creates another service. How do i return the created service?

```
syntax = "proto3";

message AddRequest {
  int32 a = 1;
  int32 b = 2;
}
message AddResponse { int32 sum = 1; }

service Calculator {
  rpc Add(AddRequest) returns (AddResponse) {}
}

message CreateRequest {}
message CreateResponse { Calculator calc = 1; }

service Creator {
  rpc Create(CreateRequest) returns (CreateResponse) {}
}
```

does grpc allow this? return `Calculator` in `Creator.Create` ?

Comment: AFAIK, "no, you can't do that"

Comment: but why? i am surprised. IDL used to support this.

Comment: the comparison is moot: it isn't IDL

Answer (score 3):

gRPC (with protocol buffers) is not object oriented. You pass *messages*, not objects; data, not references. The moment you pass objects you open a Pandora's box because then you need to know when to free those objects.

Most "modern" network-based communication systems are no longer object oriented. It used to be common with things like CORBA and JNI. However, when developing a system with them it becomes hard to manage. Object orientation is still common for local-only IPC mechanisms, like D-Bus and Binder.

Comment: so what is suggested for above scenario? the example i have given here is very simple. what i want is an api like `Create(args...)` not be a part of the service i want my users to use. I dont want check if service is already `Created` in each service method. So wanted to separate the two.

Comment: FWIW, Cap'n Proto is a modern RPC protocol that is object-oriented, and implements prompt, deterministic freeing of objects via reference counting. (I am the author of Cap'n Proto.)

Comment: Most common solutions, in order of complexity: 1) Do not reuse calculators across RPCs; each request will be separate and have all the operations as one formula. 2) Use a stream and bind the lifetime of the calculator to the stream. 3) Expose calculator as a resource in your API; user would call Create and get a calculator name and then would later issue commands specifying calculator name. You would need to charge the user for their calculator instances, limit number of calculators per user, auto-delete old instances, or similar to manage the resource.